# Jquery post issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I'll try to explain this as best as possible.

I have a main html page with a dropdown. When the dropdown is clicked, the jquery loads another external html into a DIV on the page. There are a couple of dropdown items, so 2 different external htmls are being loaded into the same DIV depending on which dropdown selection was made. That works fine.

The issue I'm having is that on the additional html files that get loaded, I have some jquery that updates labels based on buttons or links clicked in the page. Everything works fine till I use the main dropdown to change the page/div selection, and then any jquery inside the additional HTML files seems to act multiple times, with the # of times equaling how many times the dropdown has been selected.

So for example, if I select "users" from the main dropdown, it loads an  html with a list of users where I can remove or add new users and then add some groups to that user. The first time I load this template, things work fine. If I go back and reselect "users" from the main dropdown, now whenever I add a group or click a link to make user changes, it acts as if I have clicked it multiple times. If I reload the entire main page, this issue stops till I reselect the dropdown again more than once.

Is this an issue somewhere with jquery or could it be some other bug?

Comment: you're adding more events within other events on elements that don't go away. ***don't do that***.

Comment: time to show a minimal example of code that reproduces the problem

Comment: Is there a way to clear all the events when the template/dropdown gets selected so it doesn't do the duplicate behavior?

Comment: Here is the project I am working on. http://76.187.133.197:8890/front/

Log in as admin/1234 then click the gear in the upper right to go to the page. Select users from the drop down and add some groups. Then select categories and remove some, and watch the label that gets filled with the IDs. Now go back to users, and add a group to the user, and watch what happens.

Comment: eh, no. i'd rather not

Comment: and, yes, you can unbind events. It's covered in the docs.

Comment: What specifically would I be unbinding? The clicks work fine, except for the duplicate behavior. So, would I unbind the clicks in a line of code before the DIV gets loaded with the external?

Comment: you would.. unbind whatever events you're rebinding. or just stop rebinding them.

Comment: You are multiply-bound on single target elements (as Kevin was describing).  You need to look at where your jQuery binds are and when they run.  My guess is you have some bindings in the html of the page that is being loaded into the div so every time that pops in it gets run.  You need to reorganize the code and pull that jQuery out.

Comment: I tried moving the jquery in the specific html templates to the main html that loads them, but it wouldn't work at that point.

Comment: event delegation, or bind after they've been added.

Comment: your event delegation - `$(document).on("click", "name=[add]", function(){...` and similar - in dynamically loaded html is actually hurting you. Document accumulates all these event handlers as they are registered when new html is added to the page. Change it to `$("name=[add]").on("click", function(){...` and place this script after html.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add event.stopImmediatePropagation(); inside the click handler in the div template.

```
   $(document).on('click',"[name=removeCategory]",function(event) {
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
          ...
```

Comment: this is not a *fix*. This is a band-aid on top of the problematic code.